# Работа в командной строке

Tags: ruby, shell, tar

Есть некоторый скрипт, который делает замеры времени на архивацию файлов,

```
print 'Название файла, который архивируем: '
name_file = gets.chomp
print 'Название архива: '
name_arch = gets.chomp
#system('cd ')

for i in 1..3 do
   system('time -o time.log tar -zcvf '+name_arch+'.tar.gz '+name_file)
  f = File.open("time.log", 'r')
  while line = f.gets
    if line.grep /^(real + \d)/
      File.open('table.log', 'a')
      puts line
    end
    f.close
  end
end
```

Но при запуске, после указания названия архива и файла, tar говорит:

```
Название файла, который архивируем: *.klk
Название архива: q
tar: *.klk: Функция stat завершилась с ошибкой: Нет такого файла или каталога
tar: Завершение работы с состоянием неисправности из-за возникших ошибок
```

однако, при записи этой же команды с теми же параметрами он делает все гладко. 
Собственно почему архиватор так ведет себя?
PS скрипт лежит в одной папке с файлом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За обработку регулярных выражений аргументов в командной строке отвечает ваша облочка, bash к примеру.

```
$ echo *.log
java_error_in_PYCHARM_2538.log java_error_in_PYCHARM_5336.log pgadmin.log replay_pid2538.log
$ echo *
***ТУТ МНОГО-МНОГО ФАЙЛОВ***`
```

Когда вы запускаете команду `system`, `*.klk` не разворачивается в список файлов, а передается напрямую, будто `*.klk` и есть файл.

Попробуйте написать так:

```
system('/bin/bash -c "time -o time.log tar -zcvf '+name_arch+'.tar.gz '+name_file + '"')`
```

Вместо `/bin/bash` вы можете поставить любой другой путь к шелу. Узнать его можно выполнив команду `which` в терминале:

```
$ which bash
/bin/bash
$ which fish
/usr/bin/fish
$ which sh
/bin/sh
```

Comment: Заменил на вашу строку. Без изменений.
Gо сути, это похоже на то же самое. Даже учитывая что `*.klk` воспринимается как отдельный файл. Учитывая, что он не находит даже по явному названию `exmpl.klk`.
`system`, на сколько я понимаю, и так выводит на `/bin/bash` дописывая к команде свои переменные(если надо). Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Хм, а рабочий каталог у вас точно верно указан? А что если попробовать полный путь? `/home/QWD/myfiles/file.klk`, например

Comment: `/home/eve/script.rb` -скрипт;
`/home/eve/file.klk` -файл;

tar сам по себе ругается при вводе `tar -zcvf exmpl.tar.gz /home/eve/file.klk`
Для этого в коде закомментирован переход к файлу через `cd`

Comment: Попробовал запустить скрипт у себя - все работает: [http://pastebin.com/6VkExJEH](pastebin)

Comment: Все прошло. Оказывается, встроенный в RubyMine запуск происходил из папки `/tmp/script.rb` и в итоге он не мог ничего cделать. Однако почему он не делал этого с переходом в папку - загадка.
Спасибо!)